# Change a String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this function that must check if a character from a string is a letter, a digit or a punctuation sign, case when it returns True otherwise False. But if I test it, it doesn't work.

```
punct :: Char -> Bool
punct c | c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')'] = True 
        | c isDigit = True  
        | c isAlpha = True 
        | otherwise = False
```

This function adds a space after one of those above.

```
format :: String -> String
format s = intercalate "" [if (punct c) then (c:" ") else [c] | c <- s]
```

After That I need to delete those above, checked at punct.
Actually I think that I can replace those from punct directly with space
I've tried something like this:

```
format :: String -> String
format s = map (\c -> if punct c then (c:" ") else [c] )
```

But it's not working, any suggestions? I think i can use map and filter? Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "*delete those above*"? The punctuations?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: The signs that return true in punct, yes

Comment: When you say "it's not working", please specify what you mean. Since this code won't compile, you should say "It doesn't compile", and give the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by `c isDigit` ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is **not** working is because your `map` maps `Char`s on `String`s (so `[Char]`s). As a result the output of the `map` would be `[String]`. Nevertheless if you want to *delete* those above, your function in the map does not throw the chars away.

Furthermore you `punct` function is wrong. `isDigit`, etc. are functions. So you call it with `isDigit c`, not `c isDigit`:

```
punct :: Char -> Bool
punct c | c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')'] = True 
        | isDigit c = True  
        | isAlpha c = True 
        | otherwise = False
```

Nevertheless, you can easily make this statement more compact and transform it into:

```
punct :: Char -> Bool
punct c = isDigit c || isDigit c || c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')']
```

There are two options here: (1) either you do a *post processing* where you filter out all the punctuations; or (2) in case you delete the punctuations, you actually do a *replacement* instead of *inserting* a space.

**(1) Post processing**:

The post-processing is simply a `filter`:

```
post_format :: String -> String
post_format = filter (not . punct)
```

You better use post processing, if you still want to use the "*original*" `format` function.

**(1) Replacement**:

In that case you could use a `helper` function:

```
helper :: Char -> Char
helper x | punct x = ' '
         | otherwise = x
```

Then `format` collapses to:

```
format :: String -> String
format = map helper
```

Comment: thank you a lot. I didn't realise that I defined wrog punct because I don't know the synthax very well. Thank a lot again

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code won't compile. Let's tackle why it won't compile one issue at a time:

First off, in your `punct` function, this compilation error happens twice:

```
Foo.hs:7:11: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(Char -> Bool) -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Char’
    • The function ‘c’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘Char’ has none
      In the expression: c isDigit
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘punct’:
        c isDigit
```

What the compiler is trying to tell you here is that you wrote "call `c` as a function, passing it the argument `isDigit`", when obviously you meant that the other way around. So first we swap those:

```
punct :: Char -> Bool
punct c | c `elem` ['.', ',', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')'] = True 
        | isDigit c = True  
        | isAlpha c = True 
        | otherwise = False
```

With that fixed, your first `format` function in fact compiles:

```
format1 :: String -> String
format1 s = intercalate "" [if (punct c) then (c:" ") else [c] | c <- s]
```

And it also seems to work as advertised:

```
*Foo> format1 "a.b_c"
"a . b _c "
```

Okay, now what about that second `format` function? Well, at first it won't compile:

```
Foo.hs:18:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char] -> [[Char]]’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [Char] -> [[Char]]
    • Probable cause: ‘map’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: map (\ c -> if punct c then (c : " ") else [c])
      In an equation for ‘format’:
          format s = map (\ c -> if punct c then (c : " ") else [c])
```

The compiler is telling you here (with the "Probable cause" message) that you forgot to use `s` on the right hand side, and should have written:

```
format s = map (\c -> if punct c then (c:" ") else [c] ) s
```

But event that won't compile: (but the error message is different now)

```
Foo.hs:18:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In the expression:
        map (\ c -> if punct c then (c : " ") else [c]) s
      In an equation for ‘format’:
          format s = map (\ c -> if punct c then (c : " ") else [c]) s
```

That's saying that your result should have been a `String` (that is, a list of `Char`, or `[Char]`), but instead was a list of `String`s (that is, a `[[Char]]`)

This is because you turned each character into a string, instead of into a character. One way to fix this is to turn each character into a character:

```
format s = map (\c -> if punct c then ' ' else c ) s
```

Another way is to apply `intercalate ""` (or `concat`) as you did before to join the list of strings into a single string:

```
format s = intercalate "" $ map (\c -> if punct c then " " else [c] ) s
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I've started to understand :)